# Foreach list of objects PHP

Tags: php, arrays, object

I’m using a foreach to get a list of objects, if the I get only one object in list, it separates obeject properties, like there are 2 objects received.
Example:

```
array:11 [
  0 => "121"
  1 => "1"
  2 => {#319
    +"Codeex": "232"
    +"Codde": "2"
  }
  3 => {#320
    +"Codeex": "343"
    +"Codde": "34"
  }
  4 => {#321
    +"Codeex": "454"
    +"Codde": "2"
  }
  5 => {#322
    +"Codeex": "565"
    +"Codde": "1"
  }
  6 => {#323
    +"Codeex": "657"
    +"Codde": "1"
  }
  7 => {#324
    +"Codeex": "678"
    +"Codde": "1"
  }
  8 => {#325
    +"Codeex": "4353"
    +"Codde": "1"
  }
  9 => {#326
    +"Codeex": "1329"
    +"Codde": "1"
  }
  10 => {#327
    +"Codeex": "1334"
    +"Codde": "2"
  }
]
```

0 & 1 should look like 2, as an single object, not as 2 separate objects.

I have a foreach Where does the list of objects. In the example above foreach first item is an object that comes in another form, the key 3 is the two foreach cycle in which obtained a list of objects. Sorry for my bad english

UPDATE:

Example PHP CODE

```
foreach ($years as $year) {
        foreach (getListofObjects($year) as $object) {
            $data[] = $object;
        }
    }
var_dump($data);
```

Comment: Please show us the desired in and output to make your problem more clear!

Comment: I have a foreach Where does the list of objects. In the example above foreach first item is an object that comes in another form, the key 3 is the two foreach cycle in which obtained a list of objects. Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Please show us the PHP code, or a simplyfied version of the code. We cannot help you without it.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, foreach ($years as $year) {
  foreach (getListofObjects($year) as $object) {
   $data[] = $object;
  }
 }

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your `foreach` loops. You should look into the result of `getListofObjects($year)`. Somehow it doesn't return objects, but numbers, in the beginning. When you've worked that out, have a look at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php because the inner loop is not needed.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, This function keeps data in xml, from wsdl web sebservice directly